# p4 sync, how do you exclude files while using wildcards?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to use p4 sync to sync a specific directory to a given changelist number using wildcards but I also want to exclude a list of files that are under that directory (in subdirectories), I tried using - (both before and after using a path with wildcards) but the file never gets excluded, this the command I'm trying:

```
p4 sync //Repo/Foo/... -//Repo/Foo/Bar/Foobar.txt
```

The file exclusion seems to only work when the files/directories you are syncing don't match the files you're trying to exclude.

Answer (score 9):

In your client, you would have multiple lines:

```
//Repo/Foo/... //my_client/Repo/Foo/...
-//Repo/Foo/subdirectory/... //my_client/Repo/Foo/subdirectory/...
```

This would allow you to get everything in the Foo directory and all subdirectories *except* "subdirectory".

Answer (score 6):

You can do this if you use a label.  Create a label in your favorite editor (p4v or command line p4 label and add your two lines:

```
//Repo/Foo/...
-//Repo/Foo/Bar/Foobar.txt
```

In the revision field put `"#head"` (including quotes!) if you want the latest or a change list number.  Give the label a name - for instance "sync_butnot_foobar"

On the command line you can now sync:

```
p4 sync @sync_butnot_foobar,@sync_butnot_foobar
```

This has a huge benefit over the modify your client spec and sync head model.  If you exclude a file in your client spec, the next time you sync that file will be brought to revision 0 which probably isn't what you wanted.

Comment: lol,keep in mind this will function like a new client spec if you use the default options... meaning you will sync to revision 0 for all files not in the label

Comment: This is cool! Except "Revision:" field should be `"#head"`, not `@head`

Comment: @Saebin not if you sync to `@label,@label`

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't exclude files on a sync.  That can only be done within the client spec.  (Well, it could be done through the protections table, but that is really a different matter I think).

But if you want to sync a specific folder and only the files in that folder, use *

```
p4 sync //Repo/Foo/*
```

will get you only the files in the Foo folder.

Comment: ignore my last message, I spoke to soon :/